# Is it possible to update your inventory quantity in shopify using script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify-api

I was having a problem in updating the products quantity in shopify inventory

I already tried this code

```
app.post("/products/update", async (req, res) => {
  const { inventory_ID, product_id } = req.body;
  const shopifyUrl = "https://mynewstoretest01.myshopify.com";
  const accessToken = "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";
  const apiUrl = `${shopifyUrl}/admin/api/2023-07/products/${product_id}.json`;

    const product = new shopify.rest.Product({session: session});
    product.id = 632910392;
    product.metafields = [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "value": "newvalue",
        "type": "single_line_text_field",
        "namespace": "global"
      }
    ];
    await product.save({
      update: true,
    });

  
  });
```

so how can update the data in specific products in shopify?
like for ex. the quantity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.